# Serving content and webdav from the same website/path

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, webdav

IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008R2 is currently serving content from `D:\intranet\*`

I was wondering if I can set a Webdav path within this folder structure or I have to create an entirely new site? ie. `D:\intranet\webdav` vs. `D:\webdav`

The issue is ports. If I use a new site for the webdav, I have to use another port. I am trying to see if I can keep it on the standard 443 port instead of having to go to another port (ie. 8443).

So far:

- I have added the webdav user to the folder permissions with read, write and modify
- I have set folder authentication to basic
- I have set a webdav authoring rule to the folder, using the webdav user and I have given him all the rights

Message obtained when attempting to connect:

```
Unassumed PROPFIND response
Status: 200
   at Rei.Fs.Webdav.WebdavFs.InnerGetInfo(Uri target, DepthType depth)
   at Rei.Fs.Webdav.WebdavFs.GetInfoAndEntries(Uri targeturi)
   at Rei.Fs.Webdav.ConnectionTestForm.Check()
```

In the browser, I get a `401`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an Apache instance at my disposal and establishing a reverse proxy in front.